# Placeholders for sqlalchemy when using Like operator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't find any examples anywhere that uses the LIKE operator via sqlalchemy that allows a placeholder to the string, not even in the documentation.

```js
query = request.form.get("search")

book = Book.query.filter(Book.title.like(":query", {"query": '%' + str(query.lower()) + '%'})).all()
```

leads to

> `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps pass in the value to `like`:

```
Book.title.like('%' + str(query.lower()) + '%')
```

Comment: the title column in my books database has some upper and lower case titles, how do I make the query request so that it is case insensitive? and that solution above worked and got rid of the error, but my database is returning an empty list D:

Comment: Hi perhaps use `title.ilike()` for case-insensitive `like`

Comment: Ok so that worked! How can I start to using or_ in this case?

            book = Book.query.filter(or_(Book.title.ilike('%' + str(query.lower()) + '%', Book.author.ilike('%' + str(query.lower()) + '%')))).all()

TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined